# How to make nested page structure?

Tags: pages

For a project at work, we're needing to make support pages that reside at http://abc.com/support, and have each one of the pages be another wordpress page.
So, for instance, /support/product1/troubleshooting and /support/product1/videos would be two different wordpress pages, and the maximum depth would be two levels, like /support/product1/troubleshooting/blank-screen.

I came up with the method of making each permalink for a support page be the url that we want, but with slashes replaced with underscores, like support_product1_tutorial-videos... also, all of these pages will share a special template.  Now I need to hijack the WP routing system to tell each one of these pages to send requests for http://abc.com/support/product1/troubleshooting to the appropriate page.

Is there an easy method of doing this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

WP pages has the ability to be able to be set in hierarchal order. Therefore you can set a parent page.

What you would do first is create a support page. Then any other page that would be nested under support you would create and before you publish select support as the parent page.

You will see this option on the right side of your screen on the page editing page.

This I believe will accomplish what you are going after.